# How to fix 'fatal error' in tableview function?

Tags: swift, uitableview

Following a tutorial step by step, the "fatal error" comes up from the "cellForRowAt" function.

I already checked the identity name("ListCell") of the each tableview cells. 
But the error still is popped up in the row with `dequeueReusableCell`

Please HELP!

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let row = self.list[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListCell")!
    cell.textLabel?.text = row.title
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about *identity name* which sounds wrong.

`ListCell` must be the **`Identifier`** of the prototype cell in the Attributes Inspector (<kbd>⌥⌘4</kbd>)

[image]

And – as already mentioned in the other answers – it's highly recommended to use the API which returns a non-optional cell

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListCell", for: indexPath)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, actually I already put "ListCell" into Identifier of the Table View Cell, and put " for: indexPath " also, the other error  "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT Error" message comes in the 'AppDelegate.swift'.

Comment: Set the Exception Breakpoint to get more information about the exception.